# Regex pattern for time expression string

Tags: regex, expression, days, hour, minute

I want to parse a time expression string (has 4 groups: week(w), day(d), hour(h) and minute(m)). 
Some examples are:

1. -3w 4d 2h 1m
2. +3w 2h 1m
3. 3d 1m
4. 1d
5. ...

I came up with this pattern:

```
([+-]{0,1})([0-9]+)w?\s?(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])d?\s?([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])h?\s?([0-5][0-9])m?
```

- begin with **+** or **-** or none
- the value before week is unlimited
- the value before day is from 0 to 31
- the value before hour is from 0 to 23
- the value before minute is from 0 to 59
- whitespace(\s) is optional

But this pattern not work. Please help. Sorry for my english!

Comment: In what way won't it work?

Answer (score 1):

```
^([+-]?)([0-9]+)?w?\s*?(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])?d?\s*?([01]?[0-9]?|2[0-3])?h?\s*?([0-5]?[0-9])?m?$
```

Modified your regex.Works now.Might need more testing though.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sB4kE6/4

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for my validation:

```
 ^(?:(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]\s?(?:(?:[Aa]|[Pp])[Mm])?|(?:1[3-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$
```

It works for 24:00 and 12:00 format allowing capital am/pm.

Maybe it can help you in the right direction.